# Play only one video simultaneously

Tags: angular, video

I have video tag

```html
<div *ngFor="let video of videos">
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source [src]="video.url" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
</div>
```

there may be 10 or 100 videos. it works ok but now I have this restriction:

> Users should not be able to play more than 1 video simultaneously. Playing a video should pause all other videos.

How can I implement that?

I'm getting that data using http get and I have `sessionId` per user

```js
this._http.get('videos?sessionId=' + sessionId).subscribe(x => { this.videos = x; });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options: wrapping the video element into its own component or creating a directive for the video element. Below I show the first as an example.

**Extend your view's component with logic from the following example**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'view',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let video of videos">
      <my-video [src]="video.url" (requestPlayback)="onVideoRequestPlayback($event)"></my-video>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyViewComponent {
  @ViewChildren(MyVideoComponent) videoComponents: QueryList<MyVideoComponent>;

  onVideoRequestPlayback(targetVideo: MyVideoComponent) {
    this.videoComponents.forEach(video => video.pause());
    targetVideo.play();
  }
}
```

**The video component itself**

Here, I'm assuming clicking the element triggers video playback. If you have a different way to trigger playback you'll need to adapt this solution.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-video',
  template: `
    <video #video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source [src]="src" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  `
})
export class MyVideoComponent {
  @Output() requestPlayback: EventEmitter<MyVideoComponent> = new EventEmitter<MyVideoComponent>();
  @ViewChild('video') videoElement: ElementRef;
  @Input() src: string;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(event: Event) {
    if (this.videoElement.nativeElement.paused) {
      this.requestPlayback.emit(this);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  pause() {
    this.videoElement.nativeElement.pause();
  }

  play() {
    this.videoElement.nativeElement.play();
  }
}
```

The video component requests playback to start. However, I leave it up to the parent component to decide when to start playback. In general, when you have multiple sibling components and they need to interact with each other, you go through the parent component.

Comment: thanks for answer but on pause it's not even going in `onVideoRequestPlayback` method

Comment: How do you trigger starting and pausing of the video? The onVideoRequestPlayback function is only called when starting a video, not when pausing it. This is as intended. Because only when starting a video do we care about pausing the other videos.

Comment: It would be nice if you'd consider replying to my comment :-).

Comment: I'm not near the computer btw. Will available within 2 days and will reply to you. I'm too interested why it is not working